# NSNotificationCenter не вызывает селектор

Tags: ios, objective-c

В контроллере `SettingsController` подписываюсь на уведомления

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.title = LocalizedString(@"titleLabelSettings", @"");
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(updateLabels)
                                                 name:kNotificationLanguageChanged
                                               object:nil];
}

- (void)updateLabels {
    self.title = LocalizedString(@"titleLabelSettings", @"");
}
```

и перехожу на следующий контроллер

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:[[ChangeLanguageController alloc] init] animated:YES];
}
```

Метод `dealloc` у контроллера `SettingsController` при этом не вызывается

```
- (void)dealloc {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:kNotificationLanguageChanged object:nil];
    NSLog(@"dealloc SettingsController");
}
```

Отправляю из контроллера `ChangeLanguageController` уведомление и `SettingsController` его не получает. Почему?

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:kNotificationLanguageChanged object:nil userInfo:nil];
```

Comment: все вызывается нормально, когда контроллер на экране?

Comment: и оба контроллера видят одно и то же значение для kNotificationLanguageChanged?

Comment: Когда контроллер на экране и посылается уведомление, то селектор выполняется. AppDelegate тоже всегда уведомление обрабатывает

Comment: А в каком месте вызываете уведомление из контроллера ChangeLanguageController? У вас код в порядке. Поставьте брекпоинт в методе updateLabels и в методе dealloc. Возможно проблема в ChangeLanguageController контроллере, либо вы не видите изменений т.к свойство self.title одинаковое в обоих методах, но метод вызывается.

Comment: брейкпоинты ставил - dealloc не вызывается, и селектор тоже не вызывается

Comment: в цепочке наследований нашел [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self]; в методе viewDidDisappear. Проблема решена - спиасибо всем за поддержку !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как-то не правильно то, что ты подписываешься во viewDidLoad (может вызваться много раз), а отписываешься в dealloc.
Если он должен слушать всегда, то перенеси подписку в метод контроллера initWithNibName:.

В твоем же случае нотификейшен можно вообще убрать и вызвать `updateLabels` из метода`SettingsController viewWillAppear`.

PS: проверь все месте где есть removeObserver, скорее всего ты где-то сам отписываешься.

Comment: Начиная с ios6 вызов viewDidLoad более одного раза практически невозможен. Даже при нехватке памяти битмап слоя (layer) выгружается из памяти, а объекты UIView и CALayer сохраняются в целости. Этот исход настолько маловероятен, что даже при желании это очень сложно сделать. Поэтому подписываться в этом методе вполне нормально.

Comment: все равно сложно представить что нужно отслеживать события начиная от загрузки view и до окончания жизни. Скорее всего нужно отслеживать всю жизнь или все время отображения на экране.

Comment: Проверил на другом уникальном идентификаторе, который нигде больше не используется. Вывод - контроллер не получает уведомления, если он не находится на активном экране. Пробовал сделать подписку в методе init - результат такой же (код вызывается - проверил)